# It is possible to show square as sum n distinc squares, where n > 2?

Tags: number-theory

We know that $5^2 = 3^2 + 4^2$.
But it is possible to show $a^2$ as the sum of three or more distinct squares?

Something like that exist?
$a^2 = b^2 + c^2 + d^2$, where $b$, $c$, $d$ are distinct natural numbers.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: $a^2=1^2+1^2+\cdots+1^2$ is one way. If $a\geq 2$, you can swap four of the $1$'s for a $2$. Likewise for $3$, $4$, or any other number.

Comment: It is possible to solve any such equation. Even set some conditions. Only question is, what exactly should be sought.   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514075/are-there-identities-which-show-that-every-odd-square-is-the-sum-of-three-square/956570#956570

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Legendre's three-square theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre's_three-square_theorem) states that every number that is not of the form

$$4^n(8m+7)$$

can be written as a sum of exactly three squares. Since most (all?) squares are not of this form, the answer to your question is Yes.

Comment: Yep, all of them. Easy to show that for negative values of n this term can't be an integer. For positive values of n the term $4^n$ is a square number, hence $8m+7$ has to be a square number which is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

The complete solution for your particular case ($n=3$) was given by Catalan — just about any elementary number theory text will give the general integer parameterization of the primitive solutions, which [assuming $b$ is odd] is
\begin{align}
a &= p^2+q^2+r^2+s^2,  \\
b &= p^2+q^2-r^2-s^2,  \\
c &= 2(ps+qr), \\
d &= 2(pr-qs).
\end{align}

The complete answer for any $n \ge 2$ is given in several papers. A good introduction is [Bradley’s paper *Equal Sums of Squares*](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3620159). For a more technical matrix-based approach, read [Barnett and Mendel’s paper *On Equal Sums of Squares*](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2302941).

Comment: Those references are excellent.  How did you know about those?

Comment: @AmateurMathPirate: ESOS equations have been a focus of mine for over a decade.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they do exist! An example is $(2, 3, 6, 7)$. $\sqrt{2^2+3^2+6^2}=7$. These are called **Pythagorean quadruples**. They exist in the form $(a,b,c,d)$. There is a Wikipedia artible about this: click [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_quadruple).

A Pythagorean quadruple is mostly used to calculate the space diagonal ($d$) of a cuboid, which is equal to $\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$, where $|a|$, $|b|$ and $|c|$ are the length, width and height of the cuboid.  Here is an example:

[image]
<sub>(source: [smpn1bontang.org](http://smpn1bontang.org/tes_online/g8s2p2/U01P3EBT0536000022A.gif))</sub>

$QW$ is the space diagonal, which is equal to $\sqrt{PS^2+RS^2+WS^2}$

Comment: You have a typo - should be $3^2$, not $3^3$.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that. Thanks for the notification!