# Finding parameter solutions for equations

Tags: diophantine-equations, parametrization

How does one proceed to find parameters for equations with more variables?
For example there is $a^2+b^2=c^2$ where a solution would be of form $(a,b,c) = (u^2-t^2,2ut,u^2+t^2)$ as seen on wikipedia. There are more other parametrizations for this.
On another post on this site there was a question about $a^2+b^2=2c^2$ and the answer was $(a+b,a-b,c)$ iff a,b,c is pythagorean triple. 
So i wonder how do i proceed to find such parameters and maybe how do i check that those parameters yield all or just some of the solution for an equation like this:
$ab=cd+ef$ over integers

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Check out the articles in this answer here.   https://math.stackexchange.com/a/993608/419507.  

You can build up the solutions to square - square equations from solving linear diophantine equations.  Another way is through stereo- graphic projection,  an example of which can be found in the first chapter of the free book you arrive at by googling "The Topology of Numbers"

Comment: Here's a link to that book https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/TN/TNbook.pdf

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2773097/how-to-find-all-rational-solutions-of-x2-3y2-7/2788381#2788381

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"OP" inquired about solution for the below equation:

$ab=cd+ef$ ----$(1)$

Above equation $(1)$ has solution given below:

$(a,b,c,d)=[(5k^2-k-2),(4),(7k-6),(2k),(3k-2),(2k+4)]$ --$(2)$

For, $k=7$, we get:

$(a,b,c,e,f)=(236,4,43,14,19,18)$

Note that solution $(2)$ is not a general solution because,

any numerical solution which does not have

a factor of (b=4) on the LHS of equation $(1)$ is

not a solution for $(2)$. For example $(3*7)=(11*1)+(5*2)$,

is not satisfied by $(2)$, but is a solution to equation $(1)$.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. May i know how did you find such a solution even if it's not the general one? What steps did you took in order to arive at such solution

Comment: I'm more interested in the process of finding the solution rather the solution itself. Thanks